# Converting value dynamically from view to scope

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to auto translate the language of every menu title from the view by a session that user have in his profile. The method that I need to use is by using our API Library that we have in our php framework.

In general usage of php, we will translate a word by using this command

```
   $_lib->translate("wordToTranslate");
```

Then automatically it will translate the word of `wordToTranslate` into the language of the user have in his profile/session.

Now, since we are using IONIC and AngularJS, what I can do to achieve this is by calling a scope from template:

```
    <p>{{translatethis("wordToTranslate")}}</p>
```

In controller I will have a scope of `translatethis`

```
     $scope.translatethis = function(arg) {

        $http.post("http://example.com/API?Word=arg&Lang=1").success( function(response) {
          console.log(response); 
        });
     }
```

And I get this error

**Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached.**

It seems like the template never finish to get the real output of the `<p>{{translatethis("wordToTranslate")}}</p>`

Can any body guide me how to clean this method, please, so that I avoid the error?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue 1: Your translate request doesn't return a value so the interpolation (`{{...}}`) has nothing to interpolate!

Issue 2: Your translate request makes a `$http` request which returns a promise, not an actual value! This means you have nothing to interpolate.

My suggestion is to make a dictionary of the words and go from there.

As an example:

```
// Create some dictionaries
$scope.translatedWords = {};
$scope.requestedWords = {};

$scope.translatethis = function(arg) {
    if ($scope.translatedWords[arg]) {
        // We have already translated this word, return it
        return $scope.translatedWords[arg];
    } else {
        if (!$scope.requestedWords[arg]) {
            // We need to request the word
            // Setting this stops us from making multiple requests while the request gets resolved.
            $scope.requestedWords[arg] = true;
            requestTranslation(arg);
        }
        return '';
    }
}

// Has no need to be on $scope as it's a private function
function requestTranslation(arg) {
    $http.post("http://example.com/API?Word=arg&Lang=1").success( function(response) {
      console.log(response); 
      // Store the result of the translation into our map
      $scope.translatedWords[arg] = response.data;
    });
}
```

Comment: I just read it, and has not tested yet. But seem beautiful to me. And you seem good in Angular. Only 318? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple error i your code.

If you ant use a function you need to have a return.

example:

```
$scope.translatethis = function(arg) {

return "my trad";
 }
```

But in your case you need to call an api so you need to build something asynchrone.

The best way to complete your need is to use some specific module like angular-translate.

If you want to develop a custom solution I think you need to learn more about asynchronous function and I suggest you to regard $filter implementation that is pretty good for this type of treatment.

UPDATE:

If you want keep this part of code you can for example place on you template only some variable:

```
   <p>{{wordToTranslate}}</p>
```

and change your function like this

```
 function translatethis(varToTranslate,arg) {

    $http.post("http://example.com/API?Word=arg&Lang=1").success( function(response) {
      console.log(response); 
varToTranslate = response.data
    });
 }
```

And add on your controller something like

```
translatethis($scope.wordToTranslate,"wordToTranslate");
```

But I think it's better to use angular translate for this type of needs.

Comment: Since I am using API then what I need is to have something asynchronelly with POST / GET method, and that is the problem in the question.

Comment: I have add some info on the previous response